# dynamic breadcrumb schema

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, seo, schema

I set dynamic schema for breadcrumb in JavaScript code ,and very thing is ok. but when tested Url in the [rich result test from google](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) ,often time does not find schema for this.
when I  see inspect of my page, schema existed of the script tag.

what  is reason that don't working well.?

[image]

JavaScript code is this:

```
 <script>
    var bread = {
        "@@context": "https://www.schema.org",
        "@@type": "BreadcrumbList",
        "itemListElement": []
    }
    var exist = false;
    $('.breadcrumb li').each(function (index) {
        var item = {}
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
        if (href) item["@@id"] = "@Repository.Settings["WebSiteAddress"]" + href // OR location.protocol+"//"+location.host+href;
        else item["@@id"] = "@Repository.Settings["WebSiteAddress"]" + window.location.pathname
        item["name"] = $.trim($(this).text());

        bread.itemListElement.push({
            "@@type": "ListItem",
            "position": index + 1,
            item
        })
        exist = true;
    });
    if(exist){
        var jsonStrb = JSON.stringify(bread);
   var s2 = document.createElement("script");
   s2.type = "application/ld+json";
   s2.id = "BreadcrumbJson";
   $("body").append(s2);
    $('#BreadcrumbJson').append(jsonStrb);
    }        </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It could be because the code runs before the DOM is ready, so the RRT doesn't pick it up.

Try running it afterwards - as you're using jQuery - by wrapping your code in the `.ready` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// your code

});
```

Also, make sure you're using a valid JSON-LD syntax. Namely, special properties should have a single "@" character (e.g. `"@context"`, `"@type"`), instead of double (`"@@context"`, `"@@type"` and so on), although the code looks fine on your screenshot/localhost, unlike the separate code snippet you've provided.